# Обработка отдельных элементов в списке

Tags: php, jquery

Есть список товаров, он может состоять из 4 элементов, может из 99, etc.
Каждому элементу присваивается свой id:

```
<div class="item" id="item-20">Товар 20</div>
<div class="item" id="item-56">Товар 56</div>
<div class="item" id="item-31">Товар 31</div>
...
<div class="item" id="item-47">Товар 47</div>
```

Задача следующая:
С помощью jQuery организовать отправку в PHP-скрипт нажатого button с указанным в нем id и произвести замену этого button на ответ из PHP-скрипта

```
<div class="item" id="item-20">Товар 20 | <button id="off-item-20">Отключить</button></div>
<div class="item" id="item-56">Товар 56 | <button id="off-item-56">Отключить</button></div>
<div class="item" id="item-31">Товар 31 | <button id="off-item-31">Отключить</button></div>
...
<div class="item" id="item-47">Товар 47 | <button id="off-item-47">Отключить</button></div>
```

В случае с одним элементом использую

```
$(document).on('click','.class',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = jQuery(this).data('id') || 0;
        $("#content").load("/ajax.php",{action:"getResult", id:id});
    });
```

Но здесь нужно что-то другое.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: по листингу не ясно, как осуществляется множественный выбор айтемов и в каких отношениях с ними сабмитный батон. Да и где он,  этот батон?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin, выборка генерируется другим php-скриптом в зависимости от параметров поиска. button на каждом айтеме свой, в соответствующем div-контейнере